# Find 2 Patterns Calc Avg Print Avg AWK

Tags: awk

I am trying to do the following in `awk`:

My data looks like this:

```
REGION = ARA ---------------------------------      
Boston1/E0023        Date, Simulated
01/91   47.53815129 
02/91   50.65750607 
03/91   47.19937152 
04/91   56.61537973 
05/91   65.20709691 
06/91   41.26555885 
07/91   33.50030035 
08/91   28.53445471 
09/91   28.15509992 
10/91   42.01960281 
11/91   59.78663005 
12/91   36.73035389 
01/92   40.94643107 
02/92   39.54410249 
03/92   63.74148238 
04/92   59.17052297 
05/92   38.82535638 
06/92   44.63729125 
07/92   35.54487173 
08/92   26.69060562 
09/92   24.80315524 
10/92   56.54098106 
11/92   49.91787601 
12/92   46.36870196 
01/93   39.29539609 
02/93   52.82357496 
03/93   42.95556699 
12/12   59.29651502 
01/13   71.07555385 
02/13   67.83077701 

REGION = ARA ---------------------------------          
Eastview/EV977       Date, Simulated    
01/91   54.56       
02/91   45.67
```

This data repeats for different locations (Boston1, Eastview, etc) and the lines below are months (01, 02, etc) and years (91, 92, 93, etc).  In AWK I'm trying to identify a few specific locations say 5 out of 150 and calculate a monthly average (Jan - Dec) of column 2 for specific years (1991-2012 for example).  I'm not certain how to calculate this all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Something to get you started:

```
NF==3 {
    header=$1
}

$1~/[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]/{
    split($1, ym, "\/")
    month=ym[1]
    year=ym[2]
    avg[year]+=$2
    items[year]+=1      
}

/^$/ {
    print header
    for (i in avg) {
        print "year:", i, "avg:", avg[i]/items[i], "items", items[i]
    }
    delete avg
    delete items
}
```

output:

```
$ awk -f avg.awk input
Boston1/E0023
year: 12 avg: 59.2965 items 1
year: 13 avg: 69.4532 items 2
year: 91 avg: 44.7675 items 12
year: 92 avg: 43.8943 items 12
year: 93 avg: 45.0248 items 3
```

Comment: thanks much - is it possible to print the header for which the average is taken at some point maybe at the beginning?

Comment: @user2100039 - best way to say thanks is to uppvote and accept :-)

Comment: OK - but is there a way to extract exclusively data for the location "Eastview" in my data sample and not any other location?  My entire data set has many locations.  Maybe - if header == "Eastview"?

Answer (score 0):

For all regions or just a given region:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[/ ]"
    OFS=","
    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",month," ")
}
/Date/ {
    if ($1==location||location=="") {
        print $1
        for (i=1;i<=length(sum);i++)
            print month[i],sum[i]/count[i]
    }
    delete sum
    delete count
}
/^[0-9]/ {
    count[int($1)]++
    sum[int($1)]=sum[int($1)]+$5
}
```

All regions:

```
$ tac file | awk -f script.awk
Eastview
Jan,54.56
Feb,45.67
Boston1
Jan,49.7139
Feb,52.714
Mar,51.2988
Apr,57.893
May,52.0162
Jun,42.9514
Jul,34.5226
Aug,27.6125
Sep,26.4791
Oct,49.2803
Nov,54.8523
Dec,47.4652
```

For a given region:

```
$ tac file | awk -v location="Eastview" -f script.awk
Eastview
Jan,54.56
Feb,45.67

$ tac file | awk -v location="Boston1" -f script.awk
Boston1
Jan,49.7139
Feb,52.714
Mar,51.2988
Apr,57.893
May,52.0162
Jun,42.9514
Jul,34.5226
Aug,27.6125
Sep,26.4791
Oct,49.2803
Nov,54.8523
Dec,47.4652
```

Comment: perfect except instead of a yearly average, I need a monthly average for the years in year range 91-12, i.e,  Eastview: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec = 45.6/54.7/43.3/, etc or similar.

Comment: @user2100039 see update and accept this answer and upvote if it meets the requirements

Comment: ok, i'm running it with a location specified and it returns nothing.  should the output be printed to screen?

Comment: i'm running it with a better input file for "file" after tac and i'm getting zeros for every month.  maybe i can figure it out.

Comment: The file you are using must be a different format from your example. See it working here http://ideone.com/iCtk30 Also what `awk` do you have? Run `awk --version`

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.5  Also, my data does look slightly different: 01/1991, instead of 01/91

Comment: Your `awk` version is okay, you need to make the file in question the representative of your actual file.